# Get all items from a loop instead of only the last one

Tags: python, list, loops, scope

```
import re
def logs():
    with open("/content/contain.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()

    for items in re.finditer(r"(?P<host>(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})) - (?P<username>(.*?)) \[(?P<time>(.*?))\] \"(?P<request>(.*?))\"",logdata):
        new_dict = (items.groupdict())
    return (new_dict) 
print(logs())
```

output:

```
{'host': '30.95.91.251', 'username': 'larson8319', 'time': '21/Jun/2019:16:02:02 -0700', 'request': 'PUT /one-to-one/whiteboard HTTP/1.0'}
```

Here "contain.txt" contains a lot of data.

I want to print all the list of dictionaries but the function only prints one dictionary.

How to print all the list of dictionaries?

Comment: change `new_dict = (items.groupdict())` to `print(items.groupdict())`

Comment: Try using `file.readall()` first.

Comment: it's not the file `file.readall` won't do anything, the guy just doesn't know how to use regular expressions. 'finditer` returns a list of all matches. if you want to print each match then put a print statement inside od the for loop, as you iterate through the returned list of matches.

Comment: this problem is easy to solve but I can't answer it as I'm currently on phone.

Comment: You're right @Jared, `read()` does read everything till EOF.

Comment: Each time through the for loop, you're assigning `new_dict` to a fresh value and discarding its previous value.  So `new_dict` ends up with only the final value from the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your code keeps updating the value, so the return value would be just the final line.  You would need to accumulate the list.

```py
import re
def logs():
    with open("/content/contain.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()
    new_dict = []

    for items in re.finditer(r"(?P<host>(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})) - (?P<username>(.*?)) \[(?P<time>(.*?))\] \"(?P<request>(.*?))\"",logdata):
        new_dict.append(items.groupdict())
    return (new_dict) 
print(logs())
```

If your list is too huge to keep in the memory, you may want to print line-by-line as @Jared comments, instead of appending to the list.  An example is below.

```py
import re
def logs():
    with open("/content/contain.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()

    for items in re.finditer(r"(?P<host>(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})) - (?P<username>(.*?)) \[(?P<time>(.*?))\] \"(?P<request>(.*?))\"",logdata):
        new_dict = items.groupdict()
        print(new_dict)

logs()
```

Comment: If the file's huge `file.read()` is already the wrong way to go: `for line in file` would be more memory-friendly.

Comment: @ggorien That's true.  This answer does not take that into account because this part seems to be working for the OP, though.